# Por que me me aparece el siguiente error Number of variables doesn't match number of parameters in prepared statement

Tags: php, mysqli

Quiero desplegar la lista de todos los usuarios registrados en pantalla, El codigo muestra todos los usuarios registrados pero aun asi me aparece el mensaje de error

> Number of variables doesn't match number of parameters in prepared statement.

Como lo soluciono?

```
<?php
$mysqli = new mysqli("localhost", "root", "", "usuarios");
if($mysqli->connect_error) {
  exit('Could not connect');
}

$sql = "SELECT nombre, apellido
FROM usuario";

$stmt = $mysqli->prepare($sql);
$stmt->bind_param('s', $_GET['q']);
$stmt->execute();
$stmt->store_result();
$stmt->bind_result($nombre, $apellido);


while($stmt->fetch()){
    echo "<table>";
    echo "<tr>";
    echo "<th>Nombre:</th>";
    echo "<td>" . $nombre . "</td>";
    echo "<th>Apellido:</th>";
    echo "<td>" . $apellido . "</td>";
    echo "</table>";
}

$stmt->close();

?>
```

Comment: Yo no veo en tu sentencia SQL que emplees algún marcador tales como: `?` entonces pierde sentido el uso de `$stmt->bind_param('s', $_GET['q']);`

Comment: Tu consulta es `SELECT nombre, apellido FROM usuario`, no tiene ningún parámetro (no hay placeholders `?`) y después le haces `$stmt->bind_param('s', $_GET['q']);`. A cuál parámetro `s` te refieres???

Comment: no se exactamente, pense que get almacenaria el nombre y el apellido en un arreglo

Comment: Vas a filtrar entonces usando el valor que llega de get?

Comment: En la pregunta dices que quieres desplegar **todos los usuarios registrados**. Entonces, ¿para qué son los parámetros que estarías pasando en el `$_GET`? Si no hay marcadores en tu consulta esto sobra: `$stmt->bind_param('s', $_GET['q']);` e incluso podrías usar `query()` en este caso sin ningún riesgo de inyección.

Comment: le agregue paramentros asi ```$sql = "SELECT nombre, apellido
FROM usuario WHERE nombre = ?, apellido=?";``` y ahora me salen estos errores: Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Call to a member function bind_param() on boolean in C:\wamp64\www\ajax\usuarios.php on line 11
( ! ) Error: Call to a member function bind_param() on boolean in C:\wamp64\www\ajax\usuarios.php on line 11